# Meaning of "43 miles to the gallon"

Tags: meaning

Example:

> The ideal programming book, according to publishers who sign authors to write them, is "of a high enough technical level to appeal to the professional programmer but basic enough to be highly instructive and easy to understand by the novice trying to get a foothold on the subject," As one who is signed to write such books, I consider these requirements to be on a par with designing a full-fledged competition automobile that can out-accelerate any other
>   race car and yet still **gets 43 miles to the gallon** for those persons who want an economy car. The two are not simultaneously possible. However, one must still make an attempt to offer technical materials to a broad range of readers.

I'm not sure how to exactly interpret that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Quantity X to the unit Y" is an expression for a ratio or rate in non-mathematical terms. In this case, it's 43 [MPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_automobiles), a very common way to express fuel efficiency (in America, at least, and presumably elsewhere customary units like the gallon are still used). 43 MPG is better mileage than most conventional cars will give, as anyone who owns a car in America will know.

The pattern seems to have originally meant something like "<strike>you can use</strike> [126](http://www.best-easy-apple-recipes.com/how-many-apples.html) apples **to** <strike>fill</strike> **the** bushel" (where the struck-through words can be left out), and was later generalized to any similar pair of units.

Answer (score 1):

*'...gets 43 miles to the gallon...'* means that for every gallon the car can travel 43 miles.

For example, 2 gallons would provide enough petrol for 86 miles; 3 gallons, 129 miles and so on.